# ServerSelectionTimeoutError when inserting documents in DocumentDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, amazon-s3, aws-documentdb

I have an S3 buckets with either

- json of perfumes of one brands or
- folders of one brand with perfumes in json format.

I know how to get their index but I would like to insert these objects into my documentdb database, in collections respective to their brand.

```
import boto3
import pymongo
import sys


def iterate_bucket_items(bucket):
    """
    Generator that iterates over all objects in a given s3 bucket

    See http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2 
    for return data format
    :param bucket: name of s3 bucket
    :return: dict of metadata for an object
    """


    client = boto3.client('s3')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)

    for page in page_iterator:
        if page['KeyCount'] > 0:
            for item in page['Contents']:
                yield item


##Create a MongoDB client, open a connection to Amazon DocumentDB as a replica set and specify the read preference as secondary preferred
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://user:password@datahub.cluster-1.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false') 

##Specify the database to be used
db = client.perfumes
c = 0
for i in iterate_bucket_items(bucket='datahubpredicity'):
    keyName = i['Key']
    print(keyName)
    if '/' in keyName and keyName[-1] is not '/':
        print("keyName: ", keyName)
        folder, file = keyName.split('/')
        ##Specify the collection to be used
        col = db[folder]
        content_object = s3.Object('datahubpredicity', keyName)
        file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        json_content = json.loads(file_content)
        print(json_content)
        ##Insert a single document
        col.insert_one(json_content)
    c+=1
    if c >= 6:
        break
    
    # ##Print the result to the screen
    # print(x)
    
##Close the connection
client.close()
```

But it returns:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 
datahub.cluster-1.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017: 
timed out, Timeout: 30s, 
Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6254472217824b192df5665d, 
                      topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, 
                      servers: [<ServerDescription ('datahub.cluster-1.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com', 27017) server_type: Unknown, 
                      rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('datahub.cluster-1.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017: timed out')>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the script can't connect to DocumentDB, your client connection string looks a bit wrong, not sure where you got the ssl_ca_certs parameter.
You should have something like this:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://<sample-user>:<password>@datahub.cluster-1.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false')
```

And this is assuming you have the .pem file in the same folder with the python script and the security group for DocumentDB configured correctly.